# trying to get value from another table - sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Food and Aisle.

```
Food contains the fields foodID, Name, Cost, and Sale Price.

Aisle contains foodaisleID, Aisle Name, Aisle Location AND foodID
```

What I am doing is displaying all of the foodaisleID's on my page along with the Aisle Name and the Aisles location (doing this from the Aisle table).

What I am trying to do is along with displaying all the foodaisleIDs, Aisle Name and Aisle Location, I'm trying to display the foodID and the food name too, but as that's in a different table I have no idea how to display the corresponding one. (If I choose a specific Aisle, I want to display only the foods in that aisle).

My current SQL statement is:

```
"SELECT * FROM aisle WHERE foodaisleID = $foodaisleID"
```

and then I am echo'ing out the aisle name etc, any idea how I could incorporate the other table into the statement so I can echo the food name and cost too?

I have looked at "joins" but not sure how to actually implement them in

Comment: So what exactly is the relationship between Food and Aisle? How do you know what Food is on what Aisle?

Comment: damn I forgot to mention that foodID is also in aisle!

Comment: so eventually i get a foodaisleID which is unique

Comment: The way you've described your two tables, each aisle can have only one food and a food can be in more than one aisle... I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth making foodAisleID a foreign key inside the Food table (at this point I assume that it is a primary key inside the Aisle table, so correct me if I'm wrong) so that you display the foodID and food name that correspond to the correct foodAisleID. Then you could use a join to retrieve the correct data from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM aisle JOIN food ON Food.FoodId = Aisle.FoodId WHERE foodaisleID = $foodaisleID
```

Should do the trick